# Qt Application : How to create standalone executable file for Windows (& Mac) from Mac?

Tags: c++, windows, macos, qt, qt-creator

I developed a Qt application in MacBook (El-Capitan 10.11.2) and it is ready now to be released.

What i want now, is **to create the standalone executable file for both Mac and Windows OS**.

But I don't know how !

I found this [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#static-linking) but I am unable to follow it is guidance, it looks different from what my system is showing me.

If you have any idea, please help me.

*Thank you*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, to compile an application for windows, you will need a windows machine (or at least a virtual machine). You can't compile for windows on mac.

Regarding the "standalone": The easy way is to deploy your application together with all the required dlls/frameworks and ship them as one "package". To to this, there are the tools `windeployqt` and `macdeployqt`. However, those will not be "single file" applications, but rather a collection of files.

If you want to have one single file, you will have to build Qt statically! You can to this, but you will have to do it on your own. And if you do, please notice that the LGPL-license (the one for the free version of Qt) requires you to make the source-code of your program public! That's not the case if you just link to the dynamic libraries.

### EDIT:

#### Deployment

Deployment can be really hard, because you have to do it differently for each platform. Most times you will have 3 steps

1. Dependency resolving: In this step, you collect all the exectuables/lirabries/translations/... your application requires and collect them somewhere they can find each other. For windows and mac, this can be done using the tools I mentioned above.
2. Installation: Here you will have to create some kind of "installer". The easiest way is to create a zip-file that contains everyhing you need. But if you want to have a "nice" installation, you will have to create proper "installers" for each platform. (One of many possibilities is the [Qt Installer Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/). Best thing about it: It's cross platform.)
3. Distribution: Distribution is how to get your program to the user. On Mac, you will have the App-Store, for windows you don't. Best way is to provide the download on a website created for this (like sourceforge, github, ...)

I can help you with the first step, but for the second step you will have to research the possibilities and decide for a way to do it.

#### Dependencies

Resolving the dependencies can be done by either building Qt statically (this way you will have only one single file, but gain additional work because you will have to compile Qt) or using the dynamic build. For the dynamic build, Qt will help you to resolve the dependencies:

macdeployqt is rather easy to use. Compile your app in release mode and call `<qt_install_dir>/bin/macdeployqt <path_to_your_bundle>/<bundle>.app`. After thats done, all Qt libraries are stored inside the `<bundle>.app` folder.

For windeployqt is basically the same: `<qt_install_dir>\bin\windeployqt --release <path_to_your_build>\<application>.exe`. All dependencies will be inside the build folder. (Hint: copy the `<application>.exe` in an empty directoy and run windeployqt on that path instead. This way you get rid of all the build-files).

Regarding the static build: Just google it, you will find hundreds of explanations for any platform. But unless you have no other choice but to use one single file (for whatever reason) it would recommend you to use dynamic builds. And regarding the user experience: On mac, they won't notice a difference, since in both cases everything will be hidden inside the app bundle. On windows, it's normal to have multiple files, so no one will bother. (And if you create an installer for windows, just make sure to add a desktop shortcut. This way the user will to have "a single file" to click.)

Comment: I just want to have a single file that when the user click it the application starts.

Comment: I am thankful for your answer. But I need examples, step by step guidance. A link to understand the process. Something solid I can follow. With all my respect but the internet is full of such explanations as yours without clear idea on what to do exactly.

Comment: BTW, I face the same problem creating the executable for Mac. The whole process is irritating and so unclear and ambiguous. Why is it this way ? Now I feel like I am never gonna publish my application after all this effort developing it. So mad at Qt to be honest

Comment: Well, deployment can be really tough, at least at the beginning. And you will face even more problems if you want to build static. I would recommend to to do it dynamic. I will edit my answere with a little more details. Hope that will help.

Comment: well, I am really scared now, so nervous. But, I will follow your advice and do it dynamically.

Comment: There it is. Try it out. If it's not detailed enough, I guess I can create some examples. But please try it first.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough answer (and sorry for the late reply, lack of electricity & internet).

Comment: macdeployedqt is giving me this error: `no file at "/opt/local/lib/mysql55/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib"`..

Comment: Are you using mysql in your project? If no, just ignore this error. If yes, check if the file exists or download it from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/ . in both cases, you should always check if your applications runs on an other device that is note used for developing.

Comment: No, I am using sqlite. But what after I download the file, where should I put it. I searched for /opt/local/ but I don't have such directory

Comment: Will, in Windows, I run windeployqt --release and many .dll file have been collected with some folders too. when I double click the .exe file it give me an error: `The application was unable to start correclty(0xc000a200). Click OK to close the application`.. what did I do wrong ?

Comment: Which kit did you use to build it? msvc/msvc64/mingw/winrt? If you chose winrt, you have to start the application using the start-menu. But I can't help you on that, I only deployed classic apllications for now (one of the first 3 options)

Comment: It finally works, thanks A LOT. even though it was a hideous process but now I have my application deployed. Thanks again